# How to supply a Row ID when using jqGrid 'editGridRow' to create a new row and not the auto generated Row ID jqg1

Tags: jqgrid

I'm new to jqGrid, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Basically, I am using jgGrid to display a list of dates and costs that I have read in from a file that I want the user to be able to amend or add new entries or delete existing entries. Upon the user clicking an onscreen button "Apply" to post back the form , I read out the jqGrid and post back to Server in the form of a JSON string.

My problem is that when I add new rows (via 'editGridRow'), jqGrid is using it's autogenerated jqg1, jg2, jg3, etc and the new rows are being populated at the top of grid instead of at their row id position i.e at the bottom of grid.

I am able to generate RowID's as necessary, however I do not seem to be able to supply them to 'editGridRow' when creating new entries, instead it appears I have to use the keyword "new".

As you are aware the reason I am using editGridRow instead of addRowData is that editGridRow creates a modal dialog for the user to enter the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

`This is what I would like to use to supply a row ID:
$("#tableGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', gridRowID, {reloadAfterSubmit:false});`

This is what I have to use to get the code to work:
$("#tableGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {reloadAfterSubmit:false});

Here is the code snippet I use for creating the gqGrid in my JSP:

`var gridRowID = ${costHistoryEntries}.length`

```
    $("document").ready(function() {

            $("#tableGrid").jqGrid({
                data: ${costHistoryEntries},
                datatype: "local", 
                height: 200, 
                colNames:['Date', 'Cost'],
                colModel:[ 
                        {name:'chdate', index:'chdate', width:110, sorttype:"date", editable:true, editrules:{date:true, required:true, custom:true, custom_func:checkDate}, datefmt:'d/m/Y'}, 
                        {name:'cost', index:'cost', width:160, align:"right", sorttype:"float", editable:true, editrules:{number:true, required:true}, formatter:'float'},
                ],
                autowidth: true,
                loadonce: true,
                sortname: 'chdate',
                sortorder: "desc", 
                rowList:[10, 20, 30],
                pager: jQuery('#tablePager'),
                viewrecords: true,
                editurl: '/myurl',
                caption: "Cost History Entries" }

            ); 

            $("#tableGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#tablePager", {edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:true, refresh:true});

            $("#addEntry").click(function() {
                gridRowID++;
                $("#tableGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {reloadAfterSubmit:false});
            });
    });
```

I also created a button and linked it to "addEntry" as an alternative way to adding a new row using the jqGrid Navigator "add/edit/delete/find/reload" bar. As you can see previous to loading the grid with data I stored  the number of entries in gridRowID. What I was hoping to be able to do in the "#addEntry" click function was use the updated gridRowID as a RowID parameter.

As a FYI:
In a previous version of the code I was using the following to load the data into the grid:

```
            var griddata = ${costHistoryEntries};
            for (var i=0; i <= griddata.length; i++) {
                $("#tableGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', i+1, griddata[i], "last");
            }
```

but found that I could do that same with

```
data: ${costHistoryEntries},
```

Both versions correctly create row ID's for the supplied sample data from the server:
[{"chdate":"20/05/2011","cost":"0.111"},{"chdate":"01/06/2011","cost":"0.222"},{"chdate":"07/07/2011","cost":"0.333"}]

My problem is adding new rows of data.

Further update, On the server side, as a test I intercepted the post to /myurl and updated the id from "_empty" to "7" but the new entry in jqGrid still has an autogenerated jqGrid Row ID "jqg1":

```
Key = chdate, Value = 26/09/2011
Key = oper, Value = add
Key = cost, Value = 14
Key = id, Value = _empty

Updated Key = chdate, Value = 26/09/2011
Updated Key = oper, Value = add
Updated Key = cost, Value = 14
Updated Key = id, Value = 7
```

Comment: What exactly data has the server response from the '/myurl' in case of `oper="add"` and `id="_empty"` as the parameters? The server response should be just `7`. It could be additionally important which 'Content-Type' has the server response.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite understand your requirement. You **get the input for the jqGrid from the server, but use `datatype: "local"` instead of the `datatype: "json"`** for example which instruct jqGrid to get ajax request to the server to get the data whenever as needed. Moreover you want to save the date on the server, but use `editurl: '/dummyurl'` instead of the **real** server url. The `editurl` would get the input data from the `$("#tableGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {reloadAfterSubmit:false});` and should post back the id of the new generated row. Is it not what you want?

So my suggestion would be to use some server based `datatype` (the bast is `datatype: "json"`) and in the same way use real `editurl` which save the data on the server (in the database mostly) and place in the server response the id on the new generated data item.

**UPDATED**: If you use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` option of the editGridRow you have to use [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) event handler together with `reloadAfterSubmit` which decode the server response and return the result in the format `[true,'',new_id]` For example if your server just return new rowid as the data you can use

```
$("#tableGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new",
    {
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        afterSubmit: function (response) {
            return [true, '', response.responseText];
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg         Thanks for your reply. Yes I get the data from the Server. I use datatype: "local" instead of the datatype: "json" as all I wanted to do was get data from server load it once allow the user to update it as necessary and <b>then</b> post data back the updated data to the server. All data checking is processed locally in the JSP page via java script function checkDate() which checks that the date is in a valid range that was passed as parameters in the request. My editurl is a real URL (sorry for confusion).

Comment: @adrnola: It's better to use `datatype: "json"` instead of loading data separately and use `datatype: "local"` and `data: ${costHistoryEntries}`. With respect of `ajaxGridOptions` you can customize the `ajax` request used by jqGrid if needed. You can use additionally `loadonce:true` if needed. But the   `datatype` is not your main problem.

Comment: @adrnola: The answer on your main problem you will find in the UPDATED part of my answer.

Comment: @Oleg: it looks like this answer solves http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844151/how-to-update-row-id-if-new-row-is-added-without-reload-in-jqgrid also

Comment: I tried this method to refresh row id after row primary keys are edited as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828676/how-to-refresh-jqgrid-row-id-after-primary-key-is-changed-in-form-edit-without-r but in this case row id does not change. How to change row id after for editing is used? My question referenced in previous comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844151/how-to-update-row-id-if-new-row-is-added-without-reload-in-jqgrid is deleted