# jqgrid - client-side sorting and reload on demand

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to have client side sorting (I don't want to call server each time when user clicks on column, cause I'm loading all the data). At the same time I want to give a possibility to reload grid without reloading the page, cause data can change. Client side sorting can be achieved via loadonce option, but ths option prevent reloading via trigger("reloadGrid").
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you need reload the grid *from the server* you should just reset the value of `datatype` to it's original value (after the first load from the server the original value of `datatype` will be changed to `'local'`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/315935) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067579/315935) depend on in what situation you want to reload the grid from the server.