# jqGrid reload issue

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to assign a function to the "reload Grid" button. I know there is this notation trigger("reloadGrid"), but I'd like to be able to specify a method call for the reload.

What I'm attempting to achieve with this:
I have two grids, both populated with one ajax call. Both grids are readOnly. For some reason, after searching, sorting and resorting the grids, the reload button reloads the grids, but not to its original order. I'm hoping if I could get the reload to take the function that populates the grids, the reload will be identical to the original first view.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. The process is: hide the given refresh button, and add a new one with new functionality.
[The Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067439/reload-of-jqgrid-not-happening-with-loadoncetrue/7067579#7067579)