# jqgrid Locking Up when paging or rowlist

Tags: jqgrid

We're finding that jqgrid locks up sometimes...particularly when using the Row List drop down. The data (XML) does come back from the server, I can see it in the GET, but jqgrid on the page doesn't refresh...then, most times, it locks up completely and the full page must be refreshed. I've found this happens no matter the dataset size (same thing happens with 100 rows as it does with 3000), no matter the browser, and on most of our grids I've tested.

Any hints on what to look for?

Should I be looking into overriding the default refresh that happens when row list is changed? something like is done here with the Refresh button override:
[Olegs Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067439/reload-of-jqgrid-not-happening-with-loadoncetrue/7067579#7067579)

and if so, how would I do that???

Comment: A little more to add here...

One grid I'm seeing this on has just 730 records in the table in total. If I set the Row List to 1000, nothing loads. This seems to happen also if I have 10 rows, and set the Row List to 50...not quite sure what to make of any of this.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through my Grid configuration, my HTML and such...I found that I had one broken XML element in the response. This broken XML was a bug in MY code, which always happened at exactly 2 MB of XML output. I traced this back to the server XML response, fixed the output, and now that the XML if proper the grid is paging nicely.

So, if you notice this kind of thing happening, first CDATA your XML, then check for any broken XML.