# Implement Delete In jQgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

i'm starter in jqGrid, i want Implement Delete Actin in jqGrid I writing this Code For Fill jqGrid

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $('#list');
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
        postData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Fill' },
        ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
        loadonce: true,
        direction: "rtl",
        datatype: 'json',
        height: 490,
        colNames: ['Code', 'TransportType', 'TransportTypeAbbr', 'Remark'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'TRANSPORT_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'TRANSPORT_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'TRANSPORT_ABBR', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'REMARK', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true }
        ],
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 40, 60],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'TRANSPORT_ID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'ASC',
        caption: '',
        rownumbers: true
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true },
     { height: 300, width: 300, url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=TransportType&Action=Update", reloadAfterSubmit: false },
     { height: 400, width: 500, url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=TransportType&Action=Insert", reloadAfterSubmit: false },
     { url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=TransportType&Action=Delete", reloadAfterSubmit: false },
     { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });
```

and in jQGridHandler i Write this code

```
case "TransportType":
    var transport = new TransportTypesBusiness();
    TRANSPORT_TYPES transportItem;
    switch (request.QueryString["Action"])
    {
        case "Fill":
            string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
            string pageIndex = request["page"];
            int totalRecords = 0;
            output = transport.BuildJQGridResults(Int32.Parse(numberOfRows), Int32.Parse(pageIndex), totalRecords);
            response.Write(output);
            break;
        case "FillDrop":
            output = transport.BuildJQGridResults();
            response.Write(output);
            break;
        case "Insert":
            transportItem = new TRANSPORT_TYPES  {
                TRANSPORT_NAME = request["TRANSPORT_NAME"].ToString(),
                TRANSPORT_ABBR = request["TRANSPORT_ABBR"].ToString(),
                REMARK = request["REMARK"].ToString()
            };
            bool isInsert = transport.AddNew(transportItem);
            break;
        case "Update":
            transportItem = new TRANSPORT_TYPES {
                TRANSPORT_ID = int.Parse(request["TRANSPORT_ID"].ToString()),
                TRANSPORT_NAME = request["TRANSPORT_NAME"].ToString(),
                TRANSPORT_ABBR = request["TRANSPORT_ABBR"].ToString(),
                REMARK = request["REMARK"].ToString()
            };
            bool isUpdate = transport.Update(transportItem);
            break;
        case "Delete":
            bool isDelete =
                transport.Delete(
                    transport.Find(c => c.TRANSPORT_ID == int.Parse(request["TRANSPORT_ID"].ToString())));
            break;
    }
```

When do I delete a record,I can not get `request["TRANSPORT_ID"].ToString()` value.

Please help me. thanks all

EDIT 1:
 i Edit script from this

```
 $(function () {
            var grid = $('#list');
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
                postData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Fill' },
                ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
                loadonce: true,
                direction: "rtl",
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 490,
                colNames: ['Code', 'TransportType', 'TransportTypeAbbr', 'Remark'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'TRANSPORT_ID', key: true,,hidden:true, editable:false },
                        { name: 'TRANSPORT_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'TRANSPORT_ABBR', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'REMARK', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true }
                       ],
                          cmTemplate: { width: 100, editable: true },
                prmNames: { oper: 'Action', editoper: 'Update', addoper: 'Insert',
                    deloper: 'Delete', id: 'STATUS_ID'
                },
                gridview: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [20, 40, 60],
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'TRANSPORT_ID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'ASC',
                caption: '',
                rownumbers: true
            });
             $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
                editData: { ActionPage: 'StatusType' },
                savekey: [true, 13],
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                recreateForm: true
            });

            grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true },
                    { height: 300, width: 300 },
                    { height: 400, width: 500 },
                    {},
                    { width: 460 });
```

and in handler for get

> ActionPage 
>   write this code

```
 HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        string ss = request["ActionPage"].ToString();
```

grid first load data but when  click in edit button get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the origin of your problem is that you *fill* rowids of the grid not correctly. Probably you do fill ids of the rows of the grid correctly, but just don't use the information.

By the way you use `Action` parameter with the value `"Insert"`, `"Update"` and `"Delete"`. On the other side there are already standard parameter `oper` which will be sent to the server (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server)) during the row editing. The value of `oper` parameter will be "add", "edit" and "del". So I see no need to use additional `Action` parameter during editing. I recommend you just to test for the value of `oper` parameter instead.

If you do like to have another name and values of `oper` parameter you can use prmNames option of jqGrid to change the defaults:

```
prmNames: { oper: "Action", editoper: "Update", addoper: "Insert", deloper: "Delete" }
```

I don't see any sense in the usage of `ActionPage=TransportType` additional parameter which you use in all URLs. If you do require to share the same URL `"jQGridHandler.ashx"` for some other purpose you can use `editurl: "jQGridHandler.ashx"` and add `ActionPage=TransportType` part to URLs using `postData`, `editData` and `delData` parameters.

In the same way with `oper` parameter one more parameter with the name `id` will be send to the server during the editing operations. So you can use `request["TRANSPORT_ID"]` on the server side. If you prefer another name (I don't see that it's really required) you can add `id: "TRANSPORT_ID"` property in `prmNames`. It will solve your main problem.

So if you don't want to make any modifications in the server code you can just do the following on the client side

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $('#list');
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
        editurl: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
        postData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Fill' },
        loadonce: true,
        direction: "rtl",
        datatype: 'json',
        height: "auto",
        colNames: ['Code', 'TransportType', 'TransportTypeAbbr', 'Remark'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'TRANSPORT_ID', key: true },
            { name: 'TRANSPORT_NAME', width: 200 },
            { name: 'TRANSPORT_ABBR' },
            { name: 'REMARK' }
        ],
        cmTemplate: {width: 100, editable: true},
        prmNames: { oper: 'Action', editoper: 'Update', addoper: 'Insert',
            deloper: 'Delete', id: 'TRANSPORT_ID'
        },
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 40, 60],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'TRANSPORT_ID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'ASC',
        rownumbers: true
    });
    $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
        editData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType' },
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        recreateForm: true
    });
    $.extend($.jgrid.del, {
        delData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Delete' },
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
    $.extend($.jgrid.search, {
        multipleSearch: true,
        recreateFilter: true,
        overlay: false
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {},
        { height: 300, width: 300, editData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Update' } },
        { height: 400, width: 500, editData: { ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Insert' },
            afterSubmit: function (response) {
                return [true, '', response.responseText];
            }},
        {},
        { width: 460 }
    );
});
```

I added some additional settings and used `cmTemplate` to change the defaults (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)) for `colModel` items.

One more important thing in your code which make a problem. You use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` setting. In the case it's important to return the `id` on the new created item in the response from the server on `"Insert"` operation. So use should use `response.Write(output);` to write in the body of the server response the id. Additionally you need use `afterSubmit` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954954/315935)) to get the new id from the server response and forward it to jqGrid:

```
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {},
    { height: 300, width: 300, editData: {ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Update'} },
    { height: 400, width: 500, editData: {ActionPage: 'TransportType', Action: 'Insert'},
        afterSubmit: function (response) {
            return [true, '', response.responseText];
        }},
    {},
    { width: 460 }
);
```

**UPDATED**: You can download the demo project from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm1.zip).

Comment: @ Oleg : thanks For Help Me but $.expand is not Function and Get undifine Error, Did you mean $.extend function?. please help me

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: You are welcome! You are right with [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). I just wrote the code together wither the rest of my answer, so it could contain some typing errors. I'll fix `$.expand` to `$.extend` in my answer. Another thing what I forget to wrote you: if you use `key: true` you can send more compact data in the server response. So you don't need to send the value of `TRANSPORT_ID` twice. You should just use corresponding `jsonReader`.

Comment: @ oleg: thanks but when in server side want give ActionPage value get error , is ActionPage  is undifine, please help me. thanks

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: Do you tried to use `request["ActionPage"]` where `request` is defined as `HttpRequest request = context.Request`, where `HttpContext context` is the parameter of `ProcessRequest` method of your `IHttpHandler` implementation?

Comment: @ Oleg : i write this code in Handler:  HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        string ss = request["ActionPage"].ToString(); and when i want get value Action Page get error.

Comment: I think don't read parameters editData: { ActionPage: 'StatusType' } or delete ,...

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: Do you get no error in filling of jqGrid? During willing of jqGrid you use HTTP GET so you can use `request.QueryString["Action"]`. For Edit, Add and Delete will be used HTTP POST. So `request.QueryString["Action"]` will be not defined, but if you use `editData: {ActionPage: 'TransportType'}` and `editData: {ActionPage: 'TransportType'}` you should be able to access `ActionPage` by `request["ActionPage"]`

Comment: @ Oleg : i Add in Question Edit Part , please help me. thanks

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: Probably the reason is the typing error in the code which I posted: one should use `$.extend` instead of `$.expand`. Moreover I found some syntax errors and that `ActionPage: 'TransportType'` was not used. Moreover to be able to use `$.extend($.jgrid.edit`, ... you have to use **more recent version of jqGrid**. So you should update jqGrid version which you use to the current which you get from the [download page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). If you will still have some problems I could upload a test VS2010 project for you.

Comment: @ Oleg : i download new version  But my problem is not resolved. I appreciate if you could upload a sample.

Comment: @ Oleg: Is it possible for you, I will upload the project for you, and you can Check it?

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: I made demo project for you. You can download the demo from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm1.zip).