# jqgrid dynamically change z-index of add form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, z-index

I've workarea with some jqgrid with a complex system of alert dialog. I've a problem about addForm z-index which I can't change dinamically as the others dialog.
I've a variable

```
increaseZIndex = 2000;
```

which I increase dinamically at each dialog creation:

```
increaseZIndex++;
```

But only in the addForm zIndex properties, this value doesn't change. I suppose the add Form dialog of the grid is created once and then it's only hidden and not been created as new at each new insert.
Here's the code:

```
jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pmygrid', {edit:false,add:true,del:false,search:false,refresh:false}, //options
                        {zIndex:1500,recreateForm:true}, // edit options
                        {zIndex:(increaseZIndex++),height:280,recreateForm:true, reloadAfterSubmit:true,url:"/myUrl.do",
```

and so on...
How can I force this value to change dinamically as the others? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should include `recreateForm: true` for both Add and Edit options. In the case the Add and Edit dialogs will be new created instead of making hidden/shown.

In all my projects I change `recreateForm: true` as the default setting by setting of the properties of `$.jgrid.edit` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5032879/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258377/315935) for the corresponding code examples).

Comment: I've already tried to set recreateForm:true but z-index value still doesn't change, see my edit

Comment: @Franky: The code which you posted is out of context. `recreateForm:true` is required always. The part `zIndex:(increaseZIndex++)` could work only if you **recreate** the whole grid (with resepect of `GridUnload` for example). You can try to use alternatively to define `pAdd` object as `var pAdd = {zIndex:1000,height:280,recreateForm:true, ...}` and use `jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid',...,pAdd, ...);`. Because Add parameters are **not anonymous** you can change it with `pAdd.zIndex = 1500;`

Comment: my addOptions are full of options like beforeShowForm, afterShowForme, afterComplete, about 200 lines of code i have to put all in an array??? And will it work without reloading the grid?

Comment: @Franky: `pAdd` should be defined as *object* (var pAdd = {...}) and not as *array* (`var pAdd = [...]`). Of case the object can contain methods (`beforeShowForm`, etc) allowed for `editGridRow` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events)). I can't grantee that *your code* will work in the case because you don't post it, but in general the code could work in the case without recreating the whole grid.

Comment: Succesful after a lot of work. Thanks Oleg as always n.1 in jqgrid!