# how to refresh jqgrid row id after primary key is changed in form edit without reload

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

If form editing changes primary key, row id will not change.

Row ids are created from primary key.
So after primary key editing in form row id becomes wrong.

Using reloadAfterSubmit: true, loses focus from added row so it should avoided.
How to refresh jqgrid row id after primery key is changed by form editing without realoading whole grid ?

Form edit aftersubmit method returns correct changed row new id:

```
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) { 
    var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText),
    return [true, '', json.Id];
  }
```

However jqgrid does not change added row id to this.
How to fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the primary key after editing, you can use jqgrid setCell method to change it.

here is the method [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

you can search it with "setCell" in this page.

```
$('#gridTable').setCell(rowId, 'KeyColumnName', 'Value');
```

Comment: jqgrid does this automatically: it refreshes all columns after editing including primary key columns. So this is not required. Probably I need to change row id: probably this is <tr> element id. For new row add usinfg form add we can return new row id in afterSubmit as descibed in Oleg answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954736/how-to-supply-a-row-id-when-using-jqgrid-editgridrow-to-create-a-new-row-and-n . However if new row id is returned after form editing as shown in code in question, jqgrid does not change row id. I asked how to change row id in this case